# Permutations and grouping in R

Tags: r, combinations, permutation

Assume in R we have three columns. The first is a random sample of 1:4 with replacement. The second is 1:4 repeating as needed. The third is just an index. The result should output a pasted combination of the numbers where order doesn't matter and give a count. Please, note that n is not filled-in in `sample`, but should be able to work for all n. Example as stated:

```
c1 <- sample(1:4, n, replace = TRUE)
c2 <- c(4:1)
c3 <- 1

cbind(c1, c2, c3)
```

We want our result to look like something like this:

```
11 x0
12 x1
13 x2
14 x3
22 x4
23 x5
24 x6
33 x7
34 x8
44 x9
```

Displaying `x[0:9] != 0`

Thank you for your help! Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Henrik for editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that we've solved our own question. The original problem dealt with origins and destinations not numeric values. So, I've posted that answer - it's an easy switch to numeric. Hope this helps someone in the future.

```
library(dplyr)
library(sqldf)
x<-data.frame(orig=as.character(sample(LETTERS[1:10], 100, replace=TRUE)), dest=as.character(sample(LETTERS[1:10], 100, replace=TRUE)))
x$orig<-as.character(x$orig)
x$dest<-as.character(x$dest)

x1<-sort(unique(c(x[,1], x[,2])))

x_ind<-data.frame(loc=x1, ind=1:length(x1))

xx<-sqldf("select a.*, b.ind as orig_ind from x as a left join x_ind as b on a.orig=b.loc")
xxx<-sqldf("select a.*, b.ind as dest_ind from xx as a left join x_ind as b on a.dest=b.loc")

comb<-function(orig, dest, orig_ind, dest_ind)
  {
  if (orig_ind<=dest_ind)
  {
    out<-paste(orig, dest, sep="-")
  } else 
  {
    out<-paste(dest, orig, sep="-")
  }
  return(out)
}

orig_dest<-apply(xxx, 1, function(x) comb(x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]))
xxxx<-data.frame(xxx, orig_dest)
```